# How to permanently set the Jenkins system property for Git plugin timeout?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have read that the Git plugin has a configuration property that enables me to change the timeout on git operations (currently 400) [1,2]. The reason I want to change this is that right now I frequently see that there is a process running and taking up gobs of CPU. The last part of its properties show:

```
...lifecycle -jar "...jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut=400
```

I found two code changes (in different places) by reading the jira tickets:

```
public static int TIMEOUT = Integer.getInteger(Git.class.getName() + ".timeOut", 10);

f.entry(title:_("Timeout (in minutes) for clone and fetch operations"), field:"timeout") {
```

I cannot see anything in the GUI to modify the timeout.

I tried adding to both my .\Jenkins\plugins\git-client\META-INF\maven\org.jenkins-ci.plugins\git-client\pom.xml's properties section:
    30

I read that changing the java call will work, but I want every restart/etc to persist this change, so I would like to edit a file somewhere to do it. Is there a way to do this?
My Jenkins is on Windows Server 2012, in case that changes things.
thank you!

1.[] ;1.10.1 (July 30, 2014)  Timeout on checkout can be adjusted (JENKINS-22400) ; ; https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin

2.[] ; ; X.[JENKINS-11286] Git plugin does not timeout - Jenkins JIRA ; ; https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11286

Comment: There should be an option *Additional behaviours -> Add -> Advanced Checkout behaviours -> Timeout (in minutes) ...*

Comment: @SevenEleven, yes, I did see that, but does it apply to the fetch as well? FYI, In my job config, 'advanced' items I see are,  1.Under Source Code Management / Git / the Advanced opens into Name and Refspec; 2.Under Github project / Advanced is DisplayName; 3.The General / Advanced does not list GIt items; 4.SCM / Git / scroll down to Additional / Add / Checkout / Timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For checkout operations you can specify a timeout with *SCM -> Git -> Additional behaviours -> Add -> Advanced Checkout behaviours -> Timeout (in minutes) for checkout operation*

For fetching you do this with *SCM -> Git -> Additional behaviours -> Add -> Advanced clone behaviours -> Timeout (in minutes) for **clone and fetch** operations*

Comment: ty @SevenEleven so much! It seems to still call itself with '400' but then it does properly quickly timeout. This is one of the cases later on I would like to add a documentation note for the plugin, to make this easier to find.